# Upgrading windows 8 to 8.1 RTM using the iso image

Tags: windows-8

If i do so, will my program files (non-metro apps) be kept intact? The windows 8.1 setup is just way too minimalistic, providing almost no options. I dont have a broadband connection, so its not possible for me to upgrade from windows store.

Answer (score 0):

No they won't be intact. You will still need the .exe setups to get them working in Windows 8.1. The app date in the programs will also be lost.